# Async call back fires after method return (angularjs .then())

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, typescript

I have the following code: (I've tried many ways)

```
performLogin = (data: LoginRequest) => {
  var deferred = this.qService.defer();
  var response = this.httpService.get(
  myServiceURL + '&' + ObjecttoParams(data))
  .then(function (response) {
    debugger;
    this.loginResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  });
  debugger;
  deferred.resolve(response);
  debugger;
  return(this.loginResponse);
}
```

This is my constructor for this service:

```
  constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, $location: ng.ILocationService, $q: ng.IQService) {
            this.qService = $q;
            this.httpService = $http;
            this.locationService = $location;
            this.loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
            this.serviceURL = staticURL + currentServiceName;

        }
```

I'm calling to performLogin in my controller, who expect to receive a "LoginResponse" class, but because the .then() is happening later, my "return this.loginResponse) happens before the .then() is even called.

How to I make him wait for the .then() to complete before returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q gives you the ability to create promises, which are very helpful for handling async operations. But the http service returns a promise, so need to create your own.

The promise is what you want to return from this method which will allow the consumer of this method to handle the result asynchronously.

```
performLogin = (data: LoginRequest): ng.IPromise<LoginResponse> => {
  var response = this.httpService.get(
      myServiceURL + '&' + ObjecttoParams(data))
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  return response;
};
```

Then whatever is calling `performLogin` can do this:

```
foo.performLogin(x)
  .then((response) => {
    // do something here with the response data
  });
```

**Bonus Points**
Saving the extra boilerplate of taking the constructor dependencies and mapping them directly onto the object...

```
constructor(
    private $http: ng.IHttpService,
    private $location: ng.ILocationService,
    private $q: ng.IQService) {
  // NOT NEEDED this.qService = $q;
  // NOT NEEDED this.httpService = $http;
  // NOT NEEDED this.locationService = $location;
  this.loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
  this.serviceURL = staticURL + currentServiceName;
}
```

By adding `private` in front of the params it will automatically add them as properties to the instance. BUT they will be the name they are injected as... so you would have to use `this.$http` instead of `this.httpService`

Comment: tnx, trying right now, the Q.Promise should be $q ?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you... I have been doing a lot of node, I will update the answer accordingly... it will actually be ng.IPromise as the return type